# How can I tokenize only specific regions inside a larger file?

Tags: antlr4, tokenize

I have a grammar for a templating language, where the templates are stored as element text inside an XML document.

I use a SAX parser on the XML, process the non-template parts of it there (there's lots of other, content to handle), and when I encounter an XML element that contains a template source, I get its text content as a string and construct an ANTLRInputStream with it. This works fine, but it's not ideal because any errors end up referring to ':1,2', instead of the correct filename, line, and offset deep within the XML file.

What is a better way to handle this? Ideally I could construct an something like an ANTLRInputStream from the string, but give it a filename and starting line / column (instead of 1,2)? Or, use an ANTLRFileStream of the XML document, but only tokenize a specific region of it, providing a length and offset somehow?

Is there some way to do this using ANTLRFileStream, or the generated lexer class? Or do I need to subclass something to get this behavior?

Comment: Your approach seems to be the proper one. For correct error reporting you have to compute the final location yourself (i.e. add the line + column offset of the parent xml tag to the position reported by the parser).